# django OSError at /password-reset/ [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: python, django

пытаюсь отправлять почту для востановления пароля. впервые вижу такую ошибку. в сети вразумительного по этому поводу ничего не нашел. при чем раньше все работало и с локального хоста все отправлялось на почту без проблем. отправлять пытаюсь и сейчас с локалхоста. какие есть варианты решения?
вот мои настройки из settings.py

```
# sending email for password reset
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'google app key'
```

Comment: Ошибка намекает, что на компьютере, где работает Django, интернета вообще нет

Comment: но как то же я сейчас сюда пишу.

Comment: проблемы с интернетом нет. перепроверил. какие могут быть еще возможные варианты?

Comment: интересно что ping smtp.gmail.com в терминале выполняется и пингуется без проблем

Comment: @GeorgePotapov попробуйте альтернативной утилитой отправить письмо через указанный SMTP

Comment: прочитал что на некоторых хостингах может быть заблокирован порт 587.

Comment: но я же на локальном хосте, еще на стадии разработки отправляю. не пойму вобщем.

Comment: возможно есть способ как то разблокировать порт, или же отправлять через другой порт?

Comment: посоветуйте пожалуйста утилиты для отправки почты